# Deformation of a sphere on collision with the wall

Tags: data-structures, graphics, 3d, computational-geometry

I have made a sphere with squares(tilled with squares). For this I have taken 3 bands and each band consists of 8 points. So total 24 points. Now I have to deform the sphere on collision with wall. For this I have stored all the points in a tree data structure. Now I will traverse the tree as the ball translate and will increase the coordinate of the points (by say, 1 unit). When the collision point gets matched with any of the node in the tree, then collision has been detected. But in order to deform the sphere, I need to check its 8 neighbors and find how much area has been compressed. But how to find by how much distance the points in the sphere will get reduced(compressed) and by how much the neighbor points will be compressed. How I will know which points in the node is to be considered as their neighbors? I think the neighbors should be the children of the collided node. But how to find how much area is compressed? What are the points in that area?. How many children a node will have in my tree? Please give me some mathematical formula or procedure for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are writing about solid materials ...

1. **you need to know the math/physics background behind this**

   you will need to know the integral and vector math so Google for **mechanics of materials** something like [this](http://web.tuke.sk/fvt-knts/index.php?option=com_phocadownload&view=category&id=14&Itemid=221) ... first hit in my language. Sorry I am not confident to do the search in English but if you find materials with similar drawings ...

   most Important things you need to look for are:

   - Hook's law
   - modulus of elasticity
   - tension
   - compression

   look here [vocabulary of terminology](http://www.google.sk/url?url=http://www.umt.fme.vutbr.cz/~mkotoul/vocabulary-CA.doc&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=mXV9VM68AefMygPQhIGYBg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGIUrT2ned0GG36KMDuvZU7WG7S5g) for this matter
2. **may be a Surface/Voxel map of the sphere-oid would be a simpler choice**

   at least during computation otherwise you can pack/unpack it by your surface points tree. You will need the surface normals and integrate the spheroid by its slices
3. **you need to compile all the data needed**

   - material constants
   - handle isotropy/anisotropy
4. **during contact**

   handle each time frame as static state. Compute the actual contact forces (transform actual kinetic energy into reaction force) and then compute the new shape for contact slice. Add the deformation distribution to non contact slices. Remove energy dissipation from kinetic energy and do the next time frame

   [image: example]

   Do not forget that the wall will deform too !!! so the contact zone is not always flat !!!

**[Notes]**

Sorry for long and not exact answer but this can not be solved by simple formula. You need to do this by area integration + slid state conditions fitting